# installing on Debian Squeeze - issues with package dependencies

Tags: ros, installation, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I followed the Debian installation instructions on the wiki and I'm operating on Squeeze and all that. However, I'm encountering an error (i think) right after all the files are copied, when dependencies are being calculated.

this is what I see:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libaprutil1-dev : Depends: libpq-dev but it is not going to be installed
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: rosdep script failed with stderr
{{{
E: Broken packages

}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in 
   pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467,
in run_script
   self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200,
in run_script
   execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall",
line 556, in 
   sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall",
line 547, in rosinstall_main
   subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s
--rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(options.path, 'setup.sh'),
ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True,
executable='/bin/bash')
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 488, in check_call
   raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source
/home/aditi.nagaraj/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm
--rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

if I try to just continue, I can work through the beginner tutorials up till using 'rosdep'
i also want to work with the stage simulation package, but using 'rosmake stage' is returning errors while building the package. roswtf returns some stuff about ros master that always fails whenever I try to follow it through (sorry, can't replicate the results for some reason).

does anyone have a solution to this? this is the second time I've tried installing it, as I had the same error the first time. i chose a new directory the second time around, but still does not seem to have helped! if I should be doing something more rigorous to uninstall, please let me know!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9592/installing-on-debian-squeeze---issues-with-package-dependencies/) by [aditi](https://answers.ros.org/users/365/aditi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You're debian install seems to have some problems:

```
libaprutil1-dev : Depends: libpq-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

May be you should try to install libaprutil1-dev with aptitude:
sudo aptitude install libaprutil1-dev

or sudo aptitude install -f to try fix the problem

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-03-30**:
and please report what's happening so we can eventually change the rosdep files.